# Filter E-Commerce transactions by event

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce, reporting, filtering

I have an event that fires whenever a user picks a specific payment method. It has an event category of 'Payment Methods' and a Label of 'Finance'.

I am trying to exclude any of these transactions from my E-commerce report, ie. anyone who triggered this specific finance event.

I can't see where to filter this in Analytics, or even how to create a custom report to achieve this.

Has anyone done anything similar? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you need to do, you need to use a Custom Report.  To the best of my knowledge, this is not an option under Saved Reports.

**To create a new report**, start in Behavior>Events and select a page as the basis of the report.

Then, in the upper right hand corner select the "Edit" link.

[image]

Next, scroll down to Filters and choose Exclude and specify your exclusions there:

[image]

Finally, add the name you wish to use for your report at the top of page and save the report (button at the bottom of the page).

Once you have done this, it will show up under Customization>Custom Reports.

**Existing Custom Reports** can add similar exclusions by going to Customization> Custom Reports.  From the Actions drop down menu for your existing report, choose Edit.

You'll find similar filter options in the Edit Custom Report page.